# Best way to schedule background jobs in asp

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a asp website that allows it's users to administer some data. The user then needs to click a button so that the website should process some files. The problem is that the operation takes about 5 minute and I need that:

1. The website to be responsive. The user should interact with the website and see the status of the operation.
2. One operation must not start before the previous one has completed (like a queue) no mater which user started the operation.

QueueBackgroundWorkItem does not actually behave like a queue and cannot see the status of the operation.

BackgroundWorker I ques is out of the question.

Should I make a windows service that does the operation and the website communicates with it thru WCF?

I would also like to avoid third party software.

Comment: Why would you say `BackgroundWorker` is out of question?

Comment: You could have a List representing your queue and a thread that treasts the queue. You could check here they have many tutorials and examples of background jobs: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx

Comment: @Mederic: The ProgressChanged method does not update the content. and also like to avoid third party software. (I've edited the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a method that starts in Application_Start in a new Thread  and has an infinite loop. Every 10 seconds it verifies a queue of tasks. A task is class that store the tasks parameters. I send each task to method that runs the tasks.

The Task processing method writes information in the database so that i can see the progres.

I don't know if this is the best implementation but it satisfies my requirements of having a processing queue that the user can add, remove task and see the progress.